Proportions of device - Plotting
I'm having problems creating this plot so that all the 4 components have the right proportions. I would like to rotate the diagonal line (in the right corner) in a specific way so that it is exactly placed diagonally at the same height as the trendline of the basis plot with the two conditions x1 and x2. In other words, the dashed line of the upper right "plot" is supposed to continue the trendline of the basis plot. Then when I enlarge or minimize the plot, it shouldn't lose these proportions.
The plots on the side as well as the diagonal plot should not take up lots of space but the focus should be on the baisi plot with the data points in it.
How the plot currently looks like:

When I zoom in, the proportions change:

How it should look like regardless of any device changements:

The other two graphs are supposed to be placed right alongside the basis plot (as in the second image). They aren't relevant for the question.
Here the code to have a reproducible example:
 library("tibble")
 library("ggplot2")
 library("patchwork")

# Simulate data
rho <- 0.7
sigma <- diag(2) * (1-rho) + rho
mu <- c(0.7, 0)
set.seed(2341)
uncorrelated <- mvtnorm::rmvnorm(50, mean = mu, sigma = sigma) |>
data.frame()

# Create components
scatterplot_uncorrelated <- ggplot(uncorrelated) +
aes(x = X1, y = X2) +
geom_abline(
intercept = 0
, slope = 1
, linetype = "22"
, color = grey(0.7)
  ) +
geom_point(
aes(fill = ifelse(X2 > X1, "weird", "expected"))
, pch = 21
, color = "white"
, size = 3
 ) +
 scale_fill_manual(values = c("1", "2")) +
 coord_equal(xlim = c(-3, 4), ylim = c(-3, 4)) +
 guides(fill = "none")
 x_den <- ggplot(uncorrelated) +
 aes(x = X1) +
 stat_density(color = "black", fill = NA) +
 lims(x = c(-3, 4)) +
 theme_void(base_size = 14)
 y_den <- ggplot(uncorrelated) +
 aes(y = X2) +
 stat_density(color = "black", fill = NA) +
 lims(y = c(-3, 4)) +
 theme_void(base_size = 14)
 diag_den <- ggplot(uncorrelated) +
 geom_path(aes(x = x, y = y), data = tibble(x = c(0, dnorm(0, mean =      
 0.7, sd = 1) * 5), y = x), linetype = "22", color = grey(0.7)) +
 geom_path(aes(x = x, y = y), data = tibble(x = c(-2.85, 2.75), y =                                            
 c(2.85, -2.75)), size = 0.5) +
 coord_fixed(clip = "off") +
 theme_void()

 # Putting together the 3 graphics and a placeholder
 (x_den +
  plot_spacer() + # Placeholder for the differential diagram at the                     
  right upper corner
  scatterplot_uncorrelated +
  y_den +
  plot_layout(width = c(1, 0.3), height = c(0.3, 1)) # Einstellung der   
  relativen Plotgrößen
  ) |>
  cowplot::ggdraw() +
  # plot the the differential diagram on the top
  inset_element(
  diag_den
   , left = 0.61 -0.025
   , bottom = 0.61 -0.025,
   , right = 1 -0.025
   , top = 1 -0.025
   , align_to = "plot"
     )

I would be glad for any help, since I'm new to plotting in R and also new to Stack Overflow!
Nancy
I tried many things for example changing the sizes and proportions of the other two plots but it doesn't work as I imagined it.

You could set the aspect ratios of each plot (to 1) and then use a straightforward ggdraw or even just the simplest patchwork
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(cowplot)

# Simulate data
rho <- 0.7
sigma <- diag(2) * (1-rho) + rho
mu <- c(0.7, 0)
set.seed(2341)
uncorrelated <- mvtnorm::rmvnorm(50, mean = mu, sigma = sigma) |>
  data.frame()

# Create components
scatterplot_uncorrelated <- ggplot(uncorrelated, aes(x = X1, y = X2)) +
  geom_abline( intercept = 0 , slope = 1 , linetype = "22" , color = grey(0.7)) +
  geom_point( aes(fill = ifelse(X2 > X1, "weird", "expected")) , pch = 21 , color = "white" , size = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("1", "2")) +
  coord_equal(xlim = c(-3, 4), ylim = c(-3, 4)) +
  guides(fill = "none")+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)

scatterplot_uncorrelated

x_den <- ggplot(uncorrelated, aes(x = X1)) +
  stat_density(color = "black", fill = NA) +
  lims(x = c(-3, 4)) +
  theme_void()+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
x_den

y_den <- ggplot(uncorrelated, aes(y = X2)) +
  stat_density(color = "black", fill = NA) +
  lims(y = c(-3, 4)) +
  theme_void()+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
y_den

diag_den <- ggplot(uncorrelated) +
  geom_path(
    data = tibble(x = c(0, dnorm(0, mean = 0.7, sd = 1) * 5), y = x), 
    aes(x = x, y = y), 
    linetype = "22", color = grey(0.7)) +
  geom_path(
    data = tibble(x = c(-2.85, 2.75), y = c(2.85, -2.75)),
    aes(x = x, y = y),
    size = 0.5) +
  xlim(-3, 6) + 
  ylim(-3, 6) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
diag_den


# ggdraw(x_den + diag_den + scatterplot_uncorrelated + y_den)

x_den + diag_den + scatterplot_uncorrelated + y_den


Thank you for your help! The code works as long as the components are of the same size. However when I want to minimalize the both garphs of the side as well as the diagonal plot, the proportions change again.
